# How to link to a custom grid with pre-applied filters?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm developing a module which uses a custom model to create a grid.
The model has a field *'username'* & I would like to generated a hyperlink to the grid with a predefined username filtered, i.e displaying only the entries where the username is *Matt*.
I can't think of an example whereby the core developers do something along these lines and looking at the URL on the admin page after applying the filter in the *username* column, I only see session jargon:

> /index.php/admin/bookouts/index/key/4ed130b406cd65dc43dd190bb5ae35ec/filter/Ym9va291dF9kYXRlJTVCZnJvbSU1RD0wNCUyRjA5JTJGMjAxMyZib29rb3V0X2RhdGUlNUJ0byU1RD0wNCUyRjA5JTJGMjAxMyZib29rb3V0X2RhdGUlNUJsb2NhbGUlNUQ9ZW5fR0I=/form_key/BQUuqBB4miqqa0Hu/

Would appreciate any input.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is not 'session jargon'. It is actually the filter values encoded with `base64_encode`.
So you can generate your URL like this:

```
$filter = 'username=Jack';
$filter = base64_encode($filter);
$url = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/bookouts/index', array('filter'=>$filter));
```